# Show "results - of" of internal search in Google search result

Tags: google, google-search

I was doing some searches on Google Search and I stumbled on this

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the search results show a summary of an internal search page (the one I highlighted by red underline) on the website (homes.com and findaproperty.com). I would like to show up this kind of result in the Google search for my website internal search. How do I do it? Do I have to put some metatag or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has been [rolling out support](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/new-snippets-for-list-pages.html) for enabling display of this data (also known as "[rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170)") [for some time now](http://searchengineland.com/google-displaying-listing-numbers-in-results-snippets-88114). Paginated results are common on real estate sites, product sites and so on.

While not technically part of the push towards "semantic markup", there's an expansive piece, including a video, on [Google's own blog post on how to signal this type of content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/video-about-pagination-with-relnext-and.html).

Comment: I tried to find the rich snippet for this and couldn't. And the SO question, and the one here that I can't find, seems to work without it.

Comment: Sorry John, I had updated original answer with link (1st one) while you were typing comment...

Comment: That links explains it all.

Comment: I already tried the rel=prev/next since a week ago. It already shows the `30+ items` although it's not like the screenshot above (the `Listings 1 - 9 of 3996`). I think I'll try giving it more time.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something decides to do on its own and you can't make it happen (like most things related to their search results). But apparently if you want a chance to make this happen, based on questions I've seen here and at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109473/ecommerce-pagination-in-google-serp-description), you don't need to do anything special except include that text near pagination for your search results. That's it.